# Place SVG in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'm trying to place an svg in illustrator using extendscript. Here's basically what I'm doing

```
var doc = app.documents.add();
var p = doc.placedItems.add();
p.file = new File(svgfilepath);
```

This fails with the error

> File is in a format that cannot be placed

I am able to place the same file manually using File > Place. Am I missing some thing? Need help!

Comment: Illustrator's Javascript team still has much to learn... Does this same syntax work with other 'placeable' items such as JPEGs or PDFs?

Comment: Yes! Jpegs/Pngs are placed fine with this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By W_J_T on forums.adobe.com:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;  
var svgFile = File(Folder.desktop + '/testSVG.svg');  
doc.groupItems.createFromFile(svgFile);
```

This works!